# How to Install XMPP on Linux 32-bit OS

Tags: linux, xmpp, ejabberd, jabberd2

I am trying to install xmpp on Linux, i found the following links

> [build a chat server using openfire on centos](http://www.jangestre.com/2009/05/openfire-xmppjabber-server-centos-5.html)
>
> [set up IM on CentOS](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-an-openfire-instant-messaging-server-on-centos-5.6)
>
> [IM on Cent OS](https://library.linode.com/communications/xmpp/openfire/centos-5)

I have an IOS application and i need to build an **IM** using **jabber/xmpp** in it. There by allowing users on the application to chat among themselves.

To do this i am trying to install XMPP on the server. So, I want to know how the communication is established between

> Application User-- Server -- Application User

**How a User utilizes the xmpp configuration to send messages to another user ?**

**Can't IOS itself have the configuration? Is it necessary to install XMPP on server to accomplish this task?**

The examples i came across so far based on Window--window application(Web based).

> Can anybody explain the actual process of communication take place? How an IOS
>   user connects to XMPP installed on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install XMPP with any of of your favourite links you mentioned to understand how XMPP works A small overview is below and for more details you can see http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html & http://ceit.uq.edu.au/content/how-xmpp-works-step-step

XMPP is not wedded to any specific network architecture, to date it usually has been implemented via a client-server architecture wherein a client utilizing XMPP accesses a server over a [TCP] connection, and servers also communicate with each other over TCP connections.

The following diagram provides a high-level overview of this architecture (where "-" represents communications that use XMPP and "=" represents communications that use any other protocol).

C1----S1---S2---C3
      |
C2----+--G1===FN1===FC1
The symbols are as follows:

C1, C2, C3 = XMPP clients
S1, S2 = XMPP servers
G1 = A gateway that translates between XMPP and the protocol(s) used on a foreign (non-XMPP) messaging network
FN1 = A foreign messaging network
FC1 = A client on a foreign messaging network

Server

A server acts as an intelligent abstraction layer for XMPP communications. Its primary responsibilities are to manage connections from or sessions for other entities, in the form of XML streams to and from authorized clients, servers, and other entities
to route appropriately-addressed XML stanzas among such entities over XML streams
Most XMPP-compliant servers also assume responsibility for the storage of data that is used by clients (e.g., contact lists for users of XMPP-based instant messaging and presence applications); in this case, the XML data is processed directly by the server itself on behalf of the client and is not routed to another entity.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: So, we have to setup XMPP on server and then IOS users will make use of it right?